# Como usar ORDER BY de um dado que não vem do Banco?

Tags: php, json

Como usar ORDER BY de um dado que nao vem da db? ex:

```
$query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM db_aux ;");
while($row = $query->fetch_array())
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=";
    $url .= $row['cep_local']."&destinations=".$row['cep_user'];
    $url .= "&language=pt&mode=car&key=AIzaSyDL6_dJ-Mbi_03_g6lHhWibxY22Z2UeYZQ";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);  
}
```

Quero ordenar por esse dado que vem da consulta `json`, `DESC`

```
 $json_data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```

Comment: no seu `$json_data` tem várias linhas? como seria um exemplo do `$json_data`???

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=86830-000&destinations=86015-810&language=pt&mode=car&key=AIzaSyDL6_dJ-Mbi_03_g6lHhWibxY22Z2UeYZQ

Comment: {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Nova Londres, Londrina - PR, 86015-810, Brasil" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Rio Bom - PR, 86830-000, Brasil" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "111 km",
                  "value" : 111283
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 hora 58 min.",
                  "value" : 7101
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}

Comment: No caso é um item que você quer ordernar?

Comment: Quero ordenar pela distancia

Comment: No caso exemplo se tem um `$json_data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']` a minha pergunta é? quantos itens tem desses porque um item não precisa ser ordenado!? correto

Comment: A sim ele da o while e vem todos os ceps do banco no caso uns 50, quero ordenar do menor para o maior

Comment: porque o seu código não está errado? não deveria ser na última linha `$json_data[] = json_decode($json, true);` ???

Comment: ele esta funcionando normal só nao ordena

Comment: Já viu a documentação da API a ver se não tem nenhum parâmetro que possa passar na _query_ que retorne os dados já ordenados? Fazer este tipo de operação do lado do cliente é bastante custoso a nível de performance.

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais na ultma linha não tem que ser um `array`?

Comment: Não tem poblema, vai ser usado em um painel, nao diretamente para o cliente

Comment: eu nao entendo muito bem de json mas sempre uso como esta ai, só que nunca precisei ordenar ou receber mais de 1 dado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com algumas modificações no seu código e utilizando a função `usort` se tem um ordenação pelo campo pretendido, exemplo:

```
<?php
    $item = array(
        array('86015-810', '86830-000'),
        array('86015-820', '86840-000'),
    );
    for($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++)
    {
        $row = $item[$i];
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=";
        $url .= "{$row[0]}&destinations={$row[1]}";
        $url .= "&language=pt&mode=car&key=AIzaSyDL6_dJ-Mbi_03_g6lHhWibxY22Z2UeYZQ";
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json_data[] = json_decode($json, true);
    }


    function sort_text($a, $b) {
        $f0 = str_ireplace([' ', 'km',','], ['','','.'],
                             $a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']);
        $f1 = str_ireplace([' ', 'km',','], ['','','.'], 
                             $b['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']);

        return $f0 > $f1;
    }

    usort($json_data, 'sort_text');

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($json_data);
    echo '</pre>';
```

<sub>***Observação:*** se pode utilizar aquele `while` da pergunta, mas, a variável tem que ser um array que no caso é a `$json_data` para armazena todos os resultados e ai fazer a ordenação.</sub>

Comment: Certo o seu codigo me volta isso "esse site uso apenas para testes proprios" https://devjp.xyz/teste.php vou montar um exemplo pra você ver oque eu preciso, nao sei se deu pra entender bem

Comment: Ve ai https://devjp.xyz/cep.php quero ordenar essa lista

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais não era pra retornar ordenado?

Comment: eu nao entendi a maneira que você fez como vou apresentar 1 dado de cada vez dentro de uma div

Comment: nao consegui dar  while junto com os dados que vem da db

Comment: Você está usando `PDO` ou `MySqli`???

Comment: Estou usando MySqli

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais se fez essa alteração: `$json_data[] = json_decode($json, true);` ???

Comment: Olha eu não to entendendo como faz, por hora vou fazer ele ser enviado pro banco de la eu busco de novo e ordeno na conexão!